# NodeJS + Lingua and UTF8

Tags: node.js, utf-8

i am working on a project using NodeJS. There is a package called "Lingua" (can be installed via npm), for translating the project into different languages. Unfortunately it has turned out, that lingua doesn't work with umlauts like ä,ö,ü.
So my first thought was that there has to be a way to tell lingua to use an utf-8 charset, but i cannot find the right solution for this.

I've just implemented lingua the common way:

```
app.use(lingua(app, {
    defaultLocale: 'de-DE',
    path: __dirname + '/languages',
    storageKey: 'lang'
}));
```

Maybe someone has experiences with this :)

Update: To give an example, please install lingua via node package manager, in your app.js include it via

```
var lingua  = require('lingua');
```

and the avbove "app.use"-part.

2) Then make a json-file, called de-DE.json, which might look like:

```
{
    "test": "ä, ö and ü sind Umlaute"
}
```

3) Somewhere in your template include the lingua-variable:

```
#{lingua.test}
```

best regards

Comment: Every string in Node is usually UTF8 unless you've done something to make it otherwise. Can you make a minimal functional example demonstrating what is not working? I don't think we've for enough info for you to get any helpful responses.

Comment: Seems to work just fine. Are you sure your JSON file is saved as UTF-8? Also, can you be more specific about what you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: Okay, let's close this chapter with the words "I am an idiot" ;)... Tried out a new editor, which saved my JSON as ANSI, not UTF-8... fixed this... now it works... sorry for making demands on your time -.-... And thanks for the hint ;)